# Mac OS Mojave Import MySQLDB import trouble

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to run a program in Python 2.7, when I run the program it says

> import MySQLdb
>   ImportError: No module named MySQLdb.

I've tried to install MySQL using the command "brew install MySQL-connector-c" which worked but still gave me the error when running the program.

Answer (score 0):

If `brew install mysql-connector-c` does not work on Mac OS, you can try:

```
brew install mysql
```

or

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

or

```
pip install mysqlclient
```